# Make the DNS server update my host name

Tags: dns

I have some sort of DNS server running on my router (running [Asuswrt-Merlin](http://www.lostrealm.ca/tower/node/79), and I can run commands from another Linux computer by host name, i.e., `ping web-server`. However, when I change settings on my router, it reboots, and then referring to servers by name fails (although connecting by IP works fine).

If I reboot the server (not the router), suddenly it works again, so presumably the server is sending some sort of command.

What command is this? I'd like to run it manually with cron or something.

If it matters, the server is running Ubuntu 13.10.

Answer (score 0):

Is the router set up as a Master Browser or WINS Server? If it's a WINS Server, is your client system (the one that you're trying to connect to the Ubuntu server from) set-up to use the WINS Server explicitly or what network configuration tool are you using (distro default?) ?

The easy way out of this one is to assign a fixed IP address to the server, and then edit your hosts file on your client system to assign a hostname you want.

The hard way out would be to use `tcpdump` like @bersch suggests.